# Changing WAV format from 32-bit floating point to 16 bit PCM

Tags: python, numpy, audio, scipy, signals

I'm trying to convert my 32-bit floating point sampled WAVE file to 16-bit integer WAVE file.

I want to generate 16-bit integer WAV file from ultrasonic sine wave which range from -1.414 to 1.414. In [SciPy.io.wavfile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html), the output format is fixed according to type array which I generated. But I changed my 32-bit float format array to 16-bit by multiplying '32767' with casting to get integer format value, but the result frequency is not similar at all.

Is there any way to change my from 32-bit floating point to 16-bit PCM using SciPy library?

Comment: Do you have to absolutely convert to 16 bit `wav` or 32bit would do? Converting `float32` to `int32` seems to be keeping audio same for me. Although I tested with audible freq. If you can post part of your wav file  it will be helpful to test .

Comment: If the input ranges from -1.414 to 1.414, then you should multiply by 32767/1.414 to scale the data to 16 bit range.  Then cast the array to `np.int16`.

Comment: I tested with original [32-bit floating point sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10zQ32ch-YSeNdkqR_wDslUEyXofhx4Ei) to [16-bit PCM sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15zh4yh4QKoHHn-v-KwSutk1Dq10FG2Rt) with multiplying 32767 with casting to integer. But my original wav file is not audible but my converted one has noise not the signal.

Comment: Oh, thank you @WarrenWeckesser your advice worked! Thank you for answering to my easy question. Thank you guys!

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the [soundfile](https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile) module, which does most of the conversions for you. You'd only have to scale the range from `+-1.414` down to `+-1.0` before saving it to a 16-bit file.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about using `SciPy` for this but you could easily get your data into a 16bit integer and then use what ever audio package you like to write it to a `wav` file.

Divide your data by 1.414 so that it is in the range [-1, 1], then multiply it by 32767 so that it is within the range of an int16 variable. Then cast it using `numpy.astype()`. The solution would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np

float32_data /=1.414
float32_data *= 32767
int16_data = float32_data.astype(np.int16)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be: int16_data = float32_data.astype(np.int16)

Comment: Yes it should be! Thank you